# Undeclared Identifier related to string variable

Tags: string, c++-cli

I am new to programming when I tried to run below code (I pasted only essential parts) I got error error : 
C2065: 'myfilename' : undeclared identifier

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
namespace First_App {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace std;

// other events while clicking buttons etc . 

private: System::Void button1_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         Stream^ myStream;
         OpenFileDialog^ OpenFiledialogVariable1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
         if (OpenFiledialogVariable1->ShowDialog()==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
         {
         if ((myStream = OpenFiledialogVariable1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)

             String^ myfilename = OpenFiledialogVariable1->InitialDirectory + OpenFiledialogVariable1->FileName;
             MessageBox::Show(myfilename); // ERROR shown in this line
             myStream->Close();

         }

     }
```

I tried ans searched msdn docs, google nothing related found. I think I did  include required header file for string class but still doesnt work. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hmm. Do you really have `^` characters in your source code?

Comment: @DavidPostill That is C++/CLI .

Comment: OK ... it just look a bit strange ...

Comment: Yeah it looks odd. It effectively is a managed pointer (technically a handle to a managed reference type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing braces here:

```
if ((myStream = OpenFiledialogVariable1->OpenFile()) != nullptr) { // added

         String^ myfilename = OpenFiledialogVariable1->InitialDirectory + OpenFiledialogVariable1->FileName;
         MessageBox::Show(myfilename); // ERROR shown in this line
         myStream->Close();
} // added
```

Since you don't have braces, the myFilename declaration is not visible to the statement under it, which is in a different (outer) scope.